# Simplifying a functional equation

Tags: functions

Given a function
$f(x) = 6 + 2f(x-2) + 2f(x-3) + \cdots + 2f(1)$
Can the function $f(x)$ be found in terms of $x$ alone such that $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=6$ and $f(3)=8$?

I managed to reduce the function to the form
$f(x)= 3f(x-2) + 2f(x-3)$. 
Can it be reduced further?

Comment: Why don't you solve it? Look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(n)%3D3f(n-2)%2B2f(n-3)

Comment: I think it would be useful if you provided us with the train of thought that led to that reduced form.

Comment: $f(x+1) = 6 + 2f(x - 1) + 2f(x - 2) + ... + 2f(1)$ so $f(x + 1) - f(x) = 2f(x - 1)$. This is pretty much a Fibonacci-like sequence and can be expressed in closed form with a formula similar to Binet's.

Comment: What is in the the dots.  I don't see any pattern at all.  It can't be all the 2f (x-i) until 1, because x is a varible.  So haw do you get from 2 f (x-i) to 2f (constant integer)?

Comment: I am assuming $x$ can only be an integer, and that the definition of the recurrence is $f(x) = 6 + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{x-2}2f(i)$.

Comment: Wait.  Are saying x is a variable integer and f (3)=6+2f (1) and f (4)=6+2f (2)+2f (1)?  You should have said given a function such that... that looks like you are defining the function and that of course is not well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get
$$f(x)-f(x-1)=2f(x-2).$$
This is
$$f(x)=f(x-1)+2f(x-2).$$
Restricted to positive integers, this is a linear recurrence, soluble
by standard methods.